# Return a string that has been repeated a specified number of times, with a given separator

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop

I am having trouble trying to get my string to repeat the amount of times I want it to.

Here is my code, but I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
def respond_echo(input_string, number_of_echoes, spacer):
    
    echo_output = ''
    if len(input_string) > 0:
         for i in range(number_of_echoes):
            echo_output += (input_string+spacer) * number_of_echoes
            
    else:
        echo_output = None
            
    return echo_output
```

respond_echo('meow', 3, '~')

```
'meow~~~meow~~~meow~~~'
```

It comes out like this but I want it to look like this

```
'meow~meow~meow~'
```

Comment: Your code is not returning the result you say it is. `respond_echo('meow', 3, '~')` produces `'meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~'`. Also do you really want the final `~` in the output or do you want it to separate the values as the name suggests.

Comment: Multiplying the string by the number of echoes within a loop seems like your issue at first glance. Try choosing one method rather than using both.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected it. When I tried the code it output `meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~`.
The problem is that every time in the for loop you are multiplying the string, so I removed it. The corrected code is:

```
def respond_echo(input_string, number_of_echoes, spacer):

    echo_output = ""
    if len(input_string) > 0:
        for i in range(number_of_echoes):
            echo_output += input_string + spacer

    else:
        echo_output = None

    return echo_output
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code above produces `'meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~meow~'` because it is redundant to both use a `for` loop and multiply the string within each for loop using `*`. You could do one or the other, but `*` is nice and concise.

You almost had it though. Here is a working runnable example!

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python

def respond_echo(input_string, number_of_echoes, spacer):
    if input_string:
        echo_output = (input_string+spacer) * number_of_echoes
        return echo_output
respond_echo('meow', 3, '~')
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js" theme="darcula"></script>
```